# Why the polynomials with real coefficient and having degree >3 is not a vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

In my textbook it is written that- all polynomials with real coefficient and having degree $≤3$ is a vector space. Does it also means that $>3$ are not vector space?

Comment: You must have a zero vector but $f(x) = 0$ does not have degree greater than 3

Comment: I don't understand. Why 0 don't have degree greater than 3?

Comment: How do you define degree for a polynomial?

Comment: Exponent power of highest degree term.

Comment: Well $x^4 + x$ is in your space, $ - x^4$ also but $x^4 + x  - x^4 = x$ is not so the set of polyonomial of degree $>3$ are not stable by addition.

Answer (score 3):

Let $P_{n>3}$ be the set of polynomials with degree larger than 3. Then obviously, it does not contain an element that plays the role of zero vector. It is also not closed under addition. On the other hand, $P_{n\leq3}$ is a vector space because it contains the polynomial $P(X) = 0$ (zero vector), and it is closed under scalar multiplication and addition (taking a linear combination of 2 polynomials of degree 3 will never have degree larger than 3).

EDIT1: you seem to be struggling with the question:

'Why is the degree of $P(x) = 0$ zero?'

Let me try to answer that question for you.

For any constant $c \in \mathbb{R}$, we can write $P(X) = c = cX^0$. Hence, the highest power of $X$ we see here is $0$. Since $0$ is such a constant, it makes sense to say that $P(X) = 0$ has degree $0$.

There is actually a bit ambiguity here, since we can also write, for example $P(X) = 0*X^3$, so that's why we chose **to define** the degree of the zero polynomial as $0$. Some authors say the degree of this polynomial is $-1$ or $- \infty$, but for these kinds of exercises it is best that you define it as being $0$ to not confuse yourself with the linear algebra concepts.

EDIT2: Now you ask why $P_{n>3}$ does not have a zero polynomial.

The easy answer is, that if it would have one, it would be $P(X) = 0$! In a vector space (or more generally a group), a subspace (or subgroup) always shares the same neutral element as the mother vector space, which here, clearly is impossible.

Comment: why polynomial with degree more than 3 does not have 0 polynomial?

Comment: see my edit, it follows from unicity of the zero vector in a vector space

Comment: Ok, now, pls tell me how did you say, Pn≤3 is a vector space because it contains the zero polynomial? Doesn't the same can be applied for n>3? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Ah no. I just told you that there is no such thing as a zero polynomial in $P_{n>3}$, and any vector space must have such an element, so this set is not a vector space.

Comment: Then how Pn≤3 is vector space ? You said, it contains P(X)=0 or zero vector. How it comes? 

Comment: Yes it contains P(X) = 0 because this polynomial has degree lower or equal to 3, while P(X) = 0 cannot be an element of $P_{n>3}$ as it does not have degree greater than 0.